# Odoo record rule restrictions

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, record-rules

**What I want to happen:**

When the boolean no_edit is False and the user_id is false or the current user, the user should be able to edit the record.

**What actually happens:**

The records is always restricted for editting.

**Python code of the fields:**

```
user_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name = 'res.users',
        string = 'User ID',
        readonly = True,
    )
no_edit = fields.Boolean(
        string = "No Edit",
        copy = False,
        default = False
    )
```

**Domain:**

```
['&', '|', ('no_edit', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', user.id)]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you putting this domain? what is user there?, did you try with  [('no_edit', '=', False), '|', ('user_id', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', user.id)]

Comment: Putting the domain in a record rule which only applies to the write of the record

Comment: @dccdany just tried your suggestion and it seems to work. Don't know why mine didn't cause it' s the same at the end isn't it ?

Comment: i will respond in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain should be:

```
[('no_edit', '=', False), '|', ('user_id', '=', False), ('user_id', '=', user.id)]
```

The one that you did evaluates the first part as an & operator:

```
('user_id', '=', False) & ('user_id', '=', user.id)
```

Because it is evaluated with "Reverse Polish Notation", for more information you can search or enter this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation